# Proving existence of a maximum of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U$ be an open bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For any function $w:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ set
$$
\operatorname{Argmax}(w):=\{x\in U:w(x)=\max_Uw\}.
$$
I have to prove that, if $w\in C(U)$ (i.e. $w$ is continuous in $U$), $w<0$ near $\partial U$, while $w(x)>0$ for some $x\in U$, then $\operatorname{Argmax}(w)$ is nonempty. Some hints?

Thank Your

Comment: You should prove that $\lbrace x\in U: w(x) \geq 0\rbrace$ is closed in $U$ (and thus closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$) and then use the existence of a maximum on a compact domain. (Also: Did you perhaps mean $w:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?)

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus Yes, sorry. It is $w:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. I correct it now. But is the set $\{w(x)\geq0\}$ automatically closed if $w$ is continuous in $U$?

Comment: It's the pre-image of a closed set and therefore closed. But you need to be a bit careful in using the information about the boundary. Generally, "closed in open" is not necessarily closed. but here, the closed set is bounded away from the boundary of the open set within which it is contained.

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus Ok, I understand that the set $\{w(x)\geq0\}$ is closed. The information about the boundary says that this set is bounded away from the boundary. So this set is compact. Now should I apply the existence of a maximum on a compact domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $ w < 0 $ near $ \partial U $ and $ w(x) > 0 $ for some $ x \epsilon U $, we know by the intermediate value theorem that $ 0 \epsilon w (U) $. Then, $ w^{-1} [0, \infty) $ is nonempty. But $ [0, \infty) $ is a closed set, then, because $ w $ is continuous, $ w^{-1} [0, \infty) $ is closed. Let's call this set A. Since $ U $ is bounded and $ A \subset U $, $ A $ is closed and bounded, and therefore compact. Then, $ w | A $ (w restricted to $ A $) being a continuous function in a compact set, it reaches it's maximum by Weierstrass' theorem, that is,

$$ \exists \: u \: \epsilon  \: U \: st. w(u) = max_{x \epsilon A} w(x) $$

Since $ w < 0 $ in $ U-A $, this maximum in $ A $ should be a maximum in $ U $ too, that is,

$$ w(u) = max_{x \epsilon U} w(x) $$

Therefore

$$ u \: \epsilon \: argmax_{x \epsilon U} w(x) $$

showing this set is nonempty.

Edit: I think the nontrivial part is that the only thing I proved about $ A $ is that it is closed relative to $ U $. But to prove that $ A $ is compact I need to show that it is bounded and closed with respect to $ \mathbb R $. There you use that $ w < 0 $ close to the boundary of $ U $, because this means that the set $ w >= 0 $ is contained in a closed set inside $ U $. That is, $ A $ is a closed set with respect to a closed set and hence closed in $ \mathbb R $.

Comment: We know that  $w^{-1}[0,\infty)$ is closed in the space $U$ because   $w:U\to \Bbb R$ is continuous. But you must show that it is closed in $\Bbb R^n$ to conclude that it is compact.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet probably he shows that $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ at the end of the post (see the edit). Anyway thank you.

Comment: To the proposer: The edit appeared after my comment.... I interpret "$\; w<0$ near $\partial U\;$" to mean  $(\partial U) \cap \overline {w^{-1}[0,\infty )}=\emptyset.$.... So if $v$ is a limit point of $S=w^{-1}[0,\infty)$ then  $v\in (\overline U)\setminus \partial U=U$ (as $U$ is open), so $v\in dom (w) \cap \overline S,$ so $v\in S$  by continuity of $w$... (Closure bars denoting closure in $\Bbb R^n.)$

Comment: This is a nice way to put it, @DanielWainfleet.

To exploit the argument of relative closedness, however, my idea would be to use the fact mentioned by you that, denoting $ S = w^{-1} [0, \infty) $, $ (\partial U) \cap \bar{S} = \emptyset $ to take $ a = inf S $, $ b = sup S $, and note that there is some $ \epsilon > 0 $ for which $ S \subset [a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon] \subset U $. S being closed with respect to U means S is closed with respect with this closed interval, which in turn is closed with respect to $ \mathbb R $, making S closed in $ \mathbb R $.